# Android facebook share dialog can't read my web server https:// image instead of http://

Tags: android, facebook

Here is my code

```
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder((Activity)context)
            .setLink(getResources().getString(R.string.game_reward_share_link))
            .setName(getResources().getString(R.string.game_reward_share_name))
            .setCaption(getResources().getString(R.string.game_reward_share_caption))
            .setPicture("https://example.com/image/xxx.jpg")
            .setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.game_reward_share_description))
            .build();
```

The image (xxx.jpg) can be sucessfully shared to facebook and view properly,  but the **user can't read the JPG thumbnail when the user confirm the share dialog and post.**

**But, if I change the setPictrue URL to "http://example.com/image/xxx.jpg", the thumbnail will be shown.**

Then, I started to think about is that "https://"  coz the problem.

I double checked facebook documentation:

```
            Sending a link

            In this section, we will message a link to this document. We will accompany this link with some attributes that will show up in the message in Facebook Messenger. In all, our content will include:

            link: the url we want to share.
            name: a title.
            caption: a subtitle.
            picture: the url of a thumbnail to associate with the post.
            description: a snippet of text describing the content of the link.
            Note: For the urls (the link and the image) only "http" or "https" schemes are supported. And the name, picture, description and caption will only show up if the link is non-nil.
```

**Finally, I tested to use "https://www.google.com.hk/images/nav_logo195_hr.png". It works!!!**

So, I wonder that **what setting should be applied to the Web Server** to let facebook can read my https://   images and **show the thumbnail**.

Tested : neither png nor jpg from my web server are not work.

Web Server Config:
nginx/1.1.19

Client Config:
Facebook SDK 3.15

Comment: More, I can browse the https://example.com/image/xxx.jpg image file on desktop

Answer (score 0):

After heavy google,

I found that all android devices does not trust my server's certificate ( RapidSSL ) but in IOS !!!

and the answer is here

[RapidSSL certificate not trusted on Android tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203857/rapidssl-certificate-not-trusted-on-android-tablet)

Follow the steps in the answer will solve the problem

Also, if you are using RapidSSL, you can test it here

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO9556